# Optuna & Wandb - how to enable logging of each trial separately?

Tags: logging, optuna, wandb

Within my optuna study, I want that each trial is separately logged by wandb. Currently, the study is run and the end result is tracked in my wandb dashboard. Instead of showing each trial run separately, the end result over all epochs is shown. So, wandb makes one run out of multiple runs.

I found the following [docs](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/optuna/integration/wandb.html) in optuna:

```
Weights & Biases logging in multirun mode.

    .. code::
```

```
            import optuna
            from optuna.integration.wandb import WeightsAndBiasesCallback

            wandb_kwargs = {"project": "my-project"}
            wandbc = WeightsAndBiasesCallback(wandb_kwargs=wandb_kwargs, as_multirun=True)


            @wandbc.track_in_wandb()
            def objective(trial):
                x = trial.suggest_float("x", -10, 10)
                return (x - 2) ** 2


            study = optuna.create_study()
            study.optimize(objective, n_trials=10, callbacks=[wandbc])
```

I implemented this line of code yet it produces the following error:

`ConfigError: Attempted to change value of key "learning_rate" from 5e-05 to     0.0005657929921495451 If you really want to do this, pass allow_val_change=True to config.update()    wandb: Waiting for W&B process to finish... (failed 1).`

Did anyone succeed in implementing logging per trial in a multi-trial study?

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it now:
It seems that the optimizer that i used caused errors in the generation of a value for the learning rate when starting a new trial. Once I took the optimizer back out, the follwing implementation worked and generated separate logs in my wandb dashboard:

```
wandb_kwargs = {"project": "my-project"}
wandbc = WeightsAndBiasesCallback(wandb_kwargs=wandb_kwargs, as_multirun=True)

@wandbc.track_in_wandb()
def objective(trial):
    
    training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments( 
        "tuning", 
        num_train_epochs=1,            
        # num_train_epochs = trial.suggest_categorical('num_epochs', [3, 5, 8]),
        per_device_eval_batch_size=3, 
        per_device_train_batch_size=3, 
        learning_rate=  trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', low=0.00004, high=0.0001, step=0.0005, log=False),             
        # per_device_train_batch_size= trial.suggest_categorical('batch_size', [6, 8, 12, 18]),       
        # per_device_eval_batch_size= trial.suggest_categorical('batch_size', [6, 8, 12, 18]),  
        disable_tqdm=True, 
        predict_with_generate=True,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        # gradient_checkpointing=True,
        # weight_decay= False
        seed = 12, 
        warmup_steps=5,
        # evaluation and logging
        evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
        save_strategy = "epoch",
        save_total_limit=1,
        logging_strategy="epoch",
        logging_steps = 1, 
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        metric_for_best_model = "eval_loss",
        # use_cache=False,
        push_to_hub=False,
        fp16=False,
        remove_unused_columns=True
    )
    # optimizer = Adafactor(
    #     t5dmodel.parameters(),
    #     lr=trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', low=4e-5, high=0.0001),  #   ('learning_rate', 1e-6, 1e-3),
    #     # weight_decay=trial.suggest_float('weight_decay', WD_MIN, WD_CEIL),   
    #     # lr=1e-3,
    #     eps=(1e-30, 1e-3),
    #     clip_threshold=1.0,
    #     decay_rate=-0.8,
    #     beta1=None,
    #     # weight_decay= False
    #     weight_decay=0.1,
    #     relative_step=False,
    #     scale_parameter=False,
    #     warmup_init=False,
    # )
    
    # lr_scheduler = AdafactorSchedule(optimizer)
    data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=t5dmodel)
    trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(model=t5dmodel,
                            args=training_args,
                            train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset['train'],
                            eval_dataset=tokenized_val_dataset['validation'],
                            data_collator=data_collator,
                            tokenizer=tokenizer,
                           #  optimizers=(optimizer, lr_scheduler)
                            )       
    
    trainer.train()
    scores = trainer.evaluate() 
    return scores['eval_loss']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t5dmodel = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("yhavinga/t5-base-dutch",  use_cache=False) 
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("yhavinga/t5-base-dutch", additional_special_tokens=None)
    
    features = {
    'WordRatioFeature': {'target_ratio': 0.8},
    'CharRatioFeature': {'target_ratio': 0.8},
    'LevenshteinRatioFeature': {'target_ratio': 0.8},
    'WordRankRatioFeature': {'target_ratio': 0.8},
    'DependencyTreeDepthRatioFeature': {'target_ratio': 0.8}
    }
    
    trainset_processed = get_train_data(WIKILARGE_PROCESSED, 0, 10)  
    print(trainset_processed)
    valset_processed = get_validation_data(WIKILARGE_PROCESSED, 0,7)
    print(valset_processed)
    tokenized_train_dataset = trainset_processed.map((tokenize_train), batched=True, batch_size=1)
    tokenized_val_dataset =  valset_processed.map((tokenize_train), batched=True, batch_size=1)   
    print('Triggering Optuna study')
    study = optuna.create_study( direction='minimize', pruner=optuna.pruners.MedianPruner()) 
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=4,callbacks=[wandbc],  gc_after_trial=True)
```